# CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database sql server found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database

Tags: sql-server

Alguns dias atrás, tive um problema de erros de consistência com uma base de dados.

Tem um comportamento muito estranho após a correcção da mesma, quando executo o `CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database`, não me apresenta erros, mas no dia a seguir tenho um erro:

> Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 525764405,
>   index ID 5, partition ID 72057606300499968, alloc unit ID
>   72057606791430144 (type In-row data). Page (3:333324) is missing a
>   reference from previous page (3:333323). Possible chain linkage
>   problem.

É sempre o mesmo. Fora isto a aplicação está a funcionar normalmente.
Já verefiquei o `HW` e não tenho qualquer tipo de erros em disco, nem memória.
Tenho *backup* mas o mesmo inclui este erro de uma semana atrás.

Answer (score 0):

Também já tive esse erro e muita dor de cabeça.

Conforme pesquisas, a causa do problema é alguma instabilidade no disco. No meu caso, trabalhamos com várias máquinas em paralelo e uma delas o disco parou na madrugada, durante vários procedimentos de rotina.

Para resolver o problema eu tive que restaurar um backup estrutural da base e copiar TODOS os dados de todas as tabelas para essa nova base. Descobri que existia UM registro em uma tabela que estava "corrompido". Este registro não pode ser copiado. O problema nunca mais voltou a acontecer.

Esses dias, novamente, mas em outra base e outro servidor tive o mesmo erro. Executei um UPDATE na tabela "corrompida" da PK para ela mesma, por exemplo:

UPDATE tabela SET id = id

O erro parou de acontecer, mas não sei explicar os porquês e qual foi o motivo da causa do erro.